# High CPU Usage, HTTPD

Tags: centos, php, httpd

My server is occasionally experiencing a high load. Looking at the statistics in HTOP, I see a lot of processes with the command:

/usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL

I guess, this is a request that is coming into my server? But how do I determine which request to what script it is? Couple of those requests are above 17% cpu load and I want to optimise the CPU load on these scripts. But unsure how to determine them.

Comment: Try running `lsof -p PID` to see what open files are associated with process.